# How to stop poetry from uninstalling packages

Tags: python-3.x, dependency-management, python-poetry

I am working on a package that has dependencies which require `colorama<0.4.4`. Other software I install with pip requires `colorama==0.4.4`. When I run `poetry install` it removes `colorama` entirely, which breaks software that I use.

How can I prevent `colorama` from removing newer versions of packages? Whatever the reasons may be for that one dependency requiring old colorama, it works with the new one well enough for my use. I have tried:

- `poetry install --no-dev` (didn't work)
- `pip install colorama==0.4.3` (poetry still says `Removing colorama (0.4.4)` even though `pip show colorama` reports `0.4.3`
- I haven't tried a dedicated venv for just this package, because it seems like a needlessly complicated solution

I need to add this exception for my computer only, so it should not be part of the `pyproject.toml` file. The problem here is that the package technically conflicts with my userland; that is because of the particular unrelated programs I have installed. Other people developing this package might not be users of those programs, or might not care that they break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use poetry, poetry will manage your venv. So whenever it detects a package in it, which conflicts with the dependencies declared in the `pyproject.toml`, it will remove it. This is how it is intended and you have no way to define exceptions.

> The problem here is that the package technically conflicts with my userland; that is because of the particular unrelated programs I have installed.

This is exactly the reason why you should have one venv per project you are developing on and the aim of poetry. So just let poetry create a venv for your project with the dependencies you have defined and you don't have any conflicts with unrelated packages.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - the docs didn't make it clear to me that poetry was meant specifically for using dedicated venv's for every project but what you say makes sense. I guess the bloat of having an additional venv for each project is just an unavoidable cost of using poetry.